# Scrollable Listview to cover Main Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

What is the concept to achieve this kind of layout?

I have following layout:

**Initially**

```
-------------------------------------
|                                   |
-------------------------------------
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|            MAIN LAYOUT            |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
-------------------------------------
|                                   |
|             LISTVIEW              |
|                                   |
-------------------------------------
```

The Listview is on top of main layout. When scrolling the listview to bottom (until bottom of list), the listview will move along and cover main layout gradually:

**Final**

```
-------------------------------------
|                                   |
-------------------------------------
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|             LISTVIEW              |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
-------------------------------------
```

When scrolling listview to top, the listview will move gradually to initial state again.

Anyone has idea?

Comment: Not sure if your requirement is match with SlidingUpPanel Layout from this library https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: add the header view of the list view 
 
mListView.addHeaderView(header);

Comment: Well after I read some documentations of `AndroidSlidingUpPanel`, now my app works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
 View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.listview_header, null);
            img_header = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.header_image);
            text_header = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.text_header);

            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

I hope it's helpful to you ..!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

try this lib it will full fill your requirement.
https://github.com/kaedea/Andriod-Seamless-ViewPager-Header